# a word to describe: Who, What, Where, When

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word to describe: Who, What, Where, When.
I'm using these words when something has changed and I need to keep track of who did it, when he did it, what he did and where he did it.

Unfortunately I do not know if there is a word to describe this.

I'm not looking for the 5 W's or 'wh' words. I'm trying to find something similar to 'interrogative word' except in my case it's not an interrogation.

Comment: They are “wh words”  “Whuh words”

Comment: *metadata descriptors*?

Comment: Essentially, you want a more formal-sounding synonym for _wh-words_?

Comment: [*Interrogative*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/interrogative) (ODO, definition 1.1) doesn't necessarily mean abusive interrogation.

Comment: *Parameter*, perhaps? *Criterion*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**interrogatives**

> An interrogative word or question word is a function word used to ask a question, such as what, when, where, who, whom, why, and how.

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrogative_word)

Now I know that you said that "in your case it's not an interrogation", but **interrogatives** and **an interrogation** (i.e. an aggressive interrogation) are entirely seperate, ***they just share the same name.***

This becomes clear when you ponder upon the definition of *interrogatives* from the Cambridge Dictionary:

> a word or sentence used when asking a question

and

> [the interrogative]: the form of a sentence that is used for asking questions

[From the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/interrogative)

Here are the different forms of the interrogative (wh- words, in your case) from Wikipedia:

**Wh-questions**

> Interrogative words in English include:
>
> interrogative determiner
>
> which, what whose (personal possessive determiner)
>
> interrogative pro-form interrogative pronoun
>
> who, whom, whose (personal)
>
> what, which
>
> interrogative pro-adverb
>
> where (location)
>
> whither (goal)
>
> whence (source)
>
> when (time)
>
> how (manner)
>
> why (reason)
>
> whether and whatsoever (choice between alternatives)

Answer (score 0):

I think the W's are incidental. Seeking a noun for "**incidentals**" directed me to "**circumstances**". You could use it with a question mark - **circumstances?**

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/circumstances

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by you think they're incidental?

Comment: The question words with "W" all pertain to "incidents" (i.e. of change). The questions are posed to obtain incidental details. I was therefore thinking that "incidentals" should have a noun definition. However, I was redirected to "circumstances" instead which seems almost equivalent. Both work well in answer to the question.

Comment: Voted yet anyone?

Answer (score -1):

I have been also been thinking about this lately and have decided on `predicate`. In my context, one of the words in the group is used to define what's being asked by a user.

The user `asked how to use the feature`.

The user `asked when to use the feature`.

The user `asked where the feature is located`.

In this case, the concern is which predicate, and the words how, what, where, when, and why are simplifications of the predicate.